# SQL 'LIKE' syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I'm writing an application that needs to work on both mysql and postgresql.
I have to use `like` to compare some values.

In mysql `LIKE` it's case insensitive.
In postgresql `LIKE` it's case sensitive and `ILIKE` it's case insensitive.

What is the best way to make a solid query that works on both in case the match has to be case insensitive ?

Does PDO have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to ensure a case-insensitive LIKE is to use something like one of these:

```
LOWER(column_name) LIKE LOWER(pattern)
UPPER(column_name) LIKE UPPER(pattern)
```

Or you can up-case/down-case the `pattern` outside the SQL and just use:

```
LOWER(column_name) LIKE down_cased_pattern
UPPER(column_name) LIKE up_cased_pattern
```

I tend to use `LOWER` out of habit as lower case is easier to read and hence easier to debug.

Comment: "Q: Do all scripts have upper and lower case? A: No, as a matter of fact, most scripts do not have cases." (From the Unicode FAQ) In the general case, you can't count on a lowercase character to have an uppercase version. You also can't count on a lowercase character to map to a single uppercase character--some of them UPPER() to two characters. So lower() is safer, but just by a little bit. Don't you love living in a Unicode world?

Comment: @Catcall: A good example of a single lower case character mapping to two upper case characters comes from the exotic German language: `UPPER("ß")` is `"SS"`. I18N and L10N is such a happy fun time! Especially when you're dealing with JIS, SJIS, EUC, and Unicode Japanese at the same time without being able to read Japanese (been there, done that, glad that UTF-8 is pretty standard these days).

Answer (score 3):

This is the job of a [Database Abstraction Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer).

PDO [does not](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) do what you're looking for but there are a few PHP DALs if you [google for them](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+dal).

> PDO does not provide a database
>   abstraction; it doesn't rewrite SQL or
>   emulate missing features. You should
>   use a full-blown abstraction layer if
>   you need that facility.