# Rails MySQL ILIKE query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

My syntax is off.  I want to create a scope `by_name` that finds all `agencies` whose name attribute contains the passed in string (case insensitive).

Here is what I have:

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_name, ->(agency_name) { where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{agency_name}%") }
end
```

In the rails console I type in `agencies = Agency.by_name("foo")`.  Here is the query generated:

```
SELECT `agencies`.* FROM `agencies`  WHERE (name ILIKE '%foo%')
```

Here is the error message:

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'ILIKE '%foo%')

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
 scope :by_name, lambda { |agency_name| 
   where('name LIKE ?', "%#{agency_name}%") # not ILIKE
 }
```

[It is in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) the keyword ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

In MySQL you do not have ILIKE. Checkout [MySQL docs on string comparison functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

---

**Bonus** - you can also use [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel). Take a look:

```
scope :by_name, lambda { |agency_name| 
  where(Agency.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{agency_name}%"))
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Why yes, because [there's no such thing as `ILIKE` in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838079/sql-like-syntax). Only `LIKE`. You may have seen `ILIKE` as a case-insensitive version of `LIKE` in PostgreSQL, but your current RDBMS is different.

Your best bet is using `LOWER` on both sides to achieve mostly equivalent effect:

```
.where('LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(?)', "%#{agency_name}%")
```

Credit to [@mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4838104/2076787).

Comment: This is not an ideal solution because this will not allow the query optimiser to use an index if one exists on the name column, a better solution would be to set the collation of your table to utf8_general_ci - the ci means case insensitive, doing this will make all text matches case insensitive

Comment: @GaryBenade What if I want to allow the user to search with a case-sensitivity flag on or off?

Comment: @VaelVictus that would be, admittedly, stretching MySQL's purpose, but for lack of functional indexes, both versions (wrt. case insensitivity) can be stored and indexed instead. Or a separate search server like ElasticSearch could be used for this purpose instead.